# Loop through all the properties in a Dynamic JSON object from Clientside in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I've a JSON object as follows which is most of the time having no specific structures. This been created from the client side using jquery and sending to the server side via AJAX.

```
{
    "items": {
        "1": [{
            "text": "Man",
            "itemID": "1",
            "checked": 1,
            "sequence": 1,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }, {
            "text": "goat",
            "itemID": "2",
            "checked": 0,
            "sequence": 2,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }, {
            "text": "dog",
            "itemID": "3",
            "checked": 0,
            "sequence": 3,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }],
        "2": [{
            "text": "pizza",
            "itemID": "1",
            "checked": 1,
            "sequence": 1,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }, {
            "text": "horse",
            "itemID": "2",
            "checked": 0,
            "sequence": 2,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }, {
            "text": "paper",
            "itemID": "3",
            "checked": 0,
            "sequence": 3,
            "matchingtext": "",
            "weight": 0
        }]
    },
    "wbmode": "dd",
    "wbanswertype": "sc"
}
```

Since its not having any specific structure I cant de-serialize it using some structured classes.

So how can I traverse across all the objects of **items** such as in this case 1 and 2

Comment: create json equivalent strongly typed class, and just deserialize it using `JSON.Net`. Visit www.json2csharp.com to generate your entities.

Comment: @Amit - he said he cant create concrete classes, also the link is broken - you dont need the www!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library (available via NuGet).  Once you add reference to it in your project and import the library to your class, you can traverse through the JSON structure like this:

```
    Dim jsonString = "{""items"":{""1"":[{""text"":""Man"",""itemID"":""1"",""checked"":1,""sequence"":1,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0},{""text"":""goat"",""itemID"":""2"",""checked"":0,""sequence"":2,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0},{""text"":""dog"",""itemID"":""3"",""checked"":0,""sequence"":3,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0}],""2"":[{""text"":""pizza"",""itemID"":""1"",""checked"":1,""sequence"":1,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0},{""text"":""horse"",""itemID"":""2"",""checked"":0,""sequence"":2,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0},{""text"":""paper"",""itemID"":""3"",""checked"":0,""sequence"":3,""matchingtext"":"""",""weight"":0}]},""wbmode"":""dd"",""wbanswertype"":""sc""}"

    Dim j As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)

    For Each item As JProperty In j.Item("items")
        Dim itemObjects As JToken = item.Value
        For Each i As JObject In itemObjects
            For Each p In i
                Debug.Print(p.Key.ToString & " = " & p.Value.ToString)
            Next
        Next
    Next
```